# Constructor {0} in class {1} cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

Mi consulta se debe a que cree una subclase (libroInfantil) que extiende de la clase Libro, al reescribir el constructor en la subclase me salta un error, el cual no termino de entender:

```
Constructor Libro in class libro cannot be applied to given types; requered: boolean, String, String, int, int; found: No arguments; Reason: Actual and formal arguements lists differ in length
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
package ejerciciolibroinfantil;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 *
 * @author jorge
 */
public class EjercicioLibroInfantil {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here

        System.out.println("Ingresee los datos correspondientes");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       System.out.print("Titulo: ");
       String til = br.readLine();
       System.out.print("ISBN: ");
       String ISBN = br.readLine();
       System.out.print("Cantidad de paginas: ");
       int numPaginas = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       System.out.print("Pagina Actual: ");
       int pagAcual = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
       System.out.print("Edad requerida: ");
       int edadRec = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

       LibroInfantil lib = new LibroInfantil(false, til, ISBN, numPaginas, pagAcual,edadRec);

      lib.abierto();
      lib.mostrarLibro();
      lib.esRecomendable(edadRec);

    }

}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package ejerciciolibroinfantil;

/**
 *
 * @author jorge
 */
public class LibroInfantil extends Libro{

    private int edadRecomendado = 18;


    public LibroInfantil(boolean estado, String titulo, String ISBN,int numPaginas, int pagActual, int edadRec){

        this.estado = estado;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.numPaginas = numPaginas;
        this.pagActual = pagActual;
        this.edadRecomendado = edadRec;
    }

    public boolean esRecomendable(int edadNinyo){

        if(edadNinyo < 18)
            return true;
        return false;
    }        
}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package ejerciciolibroinfantil;

/**
 *
 * @author jorge
 */
public class Libro {

    protected boolean estado = false;
    protected String titulo ="null";
    protected String ISBN = "null";
    protected int numPaginas = 0;
    protected int pagActual = 0;

    public Libro(boolean estado, String titulo, String ISBN,int numPaginas, int pagActual){

        this.estado = estado;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
        this.numPaginas = numPaginas;
        this.pagActual = pagActual;
    }

    public void abierto(){

        this.estado = true;
        System.out.println("Libro abierto");
    }

    public void cerrado(){

        this.estado = false;
        System.out.println("Libro cerrado");
    }

    public void mostrarLibro(){

        System.out.println("Titulo del libro: "+titulo+" ISBN: "+ISBN+" Numero de pag: "+numPaginas+" Pagina Actual: "+pagActual);
    }
}
```

Comment: puede poner el error que esta teniendo Saludos

Comment: "Constructor Libro in class libro cannot  be applied to given types; requered: boolean, String, String, int, int; found: No arguments; Reason: Actual and formal arguements lists differ in length" este es el error

Comment: puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, puede acceder a editar presionado sobre el, le recomiendo que entre para que pueda ver como se formatea el codigo para que se muestre como esta ahora y no como usted lo dejo al principio, basicamente es poner 4 spc, pero lo puede hacer seleccionando el codigo en el modo edicion y pulsando sobre { } que esta en la parte superior donde escribe el codigo, ahora esta bien pero para futuras preguntas/respuesta hace que sea mas facil de leer Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede que modificando la clase siguientente:

```
package ejerciciolibroinfantil;

/**
 *
 * @author jorge
 */
public class LibroInfantil extends Libro{

private int edadRecomendado = 18;

  public LibroInfantil(boolean estado, String titulo, 
                      String ISBN,int numPaginas, 
                      int pagActual, int edadRec) {

        super(estado, titulo, ISBN, numPaginas, pagActual);

        this.edadRecomendado = edadRec; //este que usted usa no se como lo usa pero hay va.
    }

    public boolean esRecomendable(int edadNinyo){

        if(edadNinyo < 18)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

pruebe con super(params):

**UPDATE**:(resulto ser que si contaba con esos metodos al mejorar el formato pude ver que si extendia de libro, despues lo borro, aun asi pruebe por que se añade super).

---

**Nuevo**:

En base a sus preguntas en los comentarios saque algo de tiempo para analizar su codigo, pues veia que usaba la herencia, protect, this, bueno que no entendia muy bien el porque fallo/error (uno puede tener fallos de codigo "yo el primero") pero no me refiero a el fallo sino al transfondo del error y creo que esto lo puede ayudar.

> La llamada al constructor de la clase base puede ser implicita
>
> - Si se omite se llamara implicitamente al constructor por defecto:
> - Equivale a poner como primera sentencia super();
> - Si no existe el constructor por defecto en la clase base dara un    error en tiempo de compilacion
>
>   o explicita:
> - super(params); o super(); o los parametros que lleve el constructor que quiera invocar de la clase base dependera si el constructor al que
>     invocamos tiene o no    argumentos

Cuando creas clase "simples" usted abra experimentado o puede haber visto que no hace falta crear el constructor;

por ejemplo:

```
public class TestBase {


}
```

y hacer:

```
TestBase testBase = new TestBase();
```

Y crear el objeto sin ningun problema, pues el compilado ya lo crea por usted. Cuando usted crea una clase esa clase no `static` se espera que usted pueda crear instancias de la misma.

Entonces usted podria hacer tambien esto:

```
public class TestDerivada extends TestBase {

       public TestDerivada (String str){

       }         
}
```

y hacer:

```
TestDerivada test = new TestDerivada("String");
```

Por que funciona, porque se esta invocando el constructor de la clase base de forma implicita desde la clase derivada, y a que constructor, al constructor que se crea por defecto que fue mensionado antes, al ser omitido, es como si se pusiera super();

Pero ahora si usted cambia y añade un constructor:

```
public class TestBase {

   public TestBase (String str){

   }
}
```

y hace:

```
TestDerivada test = new TestDerivada("String");
```

Recivira un error en tiempo de `compilacion` (algunos ide te avisan de esto, si no tu tranquilo que ya te avisa el compilador), porque tiene que llamar al constructor de la clase base.

"Y usted puede decir vale no lo llame, pero se decia que se llamaba tambien por defecto si no se ponia nada en la clase derivada, porque era creado por el complilador bla bla".

Y si `pero` cuando la clase en este caso la base se le añade un constructor creado por usted el constructor que creaba el compilado es omitido, y por que, porque usted esta definiendo como quiere que se `comporte/logica` a la hora de crear instancias, de no ser asi alguien podria instanciarlo de una manera para la que no fue diseñada la clase.

Este es un ejemplo simple, pero si esa clase se le pasara a otra como parametro, y tubiera que tomar datos de esa `clase/instancia` para trabajar, y resulta que eso datos solo son `inicializado/creados` o lo que sea, desde el constructor que usted creo, pues seria un problema porque en el `constructor por defecto` estas "llamense" variables no estarian inicializadas o creadas o lo que usted implementara en el `construtor que diseño` (espero se entienda).

Tendria que quedar algo asi:

```
public class TestBase {

   public TestBase (String str){

   }
}
```

.

```
public class TestDerivada extends TestBase {

       public TestDerivada (String str){
           super(str);
           //super(); <- no valdria porque no esta, ni tampoco dejalo sin ninguno por lo mismo
       }         
}
```

si quisiera llamarlo de manera implicita o explicita tendria que crearlo pues, ya añadio uno antes y este otro digamos que es anulado.

Seria algo asi;

```
public class TestBase {

   public TestBase (){

   }

   public TestBase (String str){

   }
}
```

Sabiendo eso usted puede usarlo de la manera que crea mas oportuno en su codigo, (ademas de lo que le comente en los comentarios).

Comment: Pero mi clase Libro infantil, ya extiende de Libro, debo poner los metodos igual en la clase hija?

Comment: no es que como no estaba bien formateado el codigo no pude ver, ya lo corregi aun asi pruebe el codigo que le dejer con super. Saludos

Comment: ahí lo probé, me funciono de lo mejor, me podrías explicar?

Comment: tu estas usando la herencia, de libro a libroInfantil, cuando llamas al constructor de la clase derivada no estabas incluyendo el de la clase padre y esto lo puedes hacer con super(params) donde params son los argumentos necesarios para la clase de la que hablamos (superior), no se si me explique bien espero me entiendas, si no te quedo claro comenta Saludos

Comment: si lo eh captado!, muchas gracias @Angel Angel

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que Libro tiene solo un constructor, y se le deben pasar los parámetros a ese constructor. Para corregirlo:

```
public class Libro{
  protected boolean estado = false;
  protected String titulo ="null";
  protected String ISBN = "null";
  protected int numPaginas = 0;
  protected int pagActual = 0;

  public Libro(boolean estado, String titulo, String isbn, 
    int numPaginas, int paginaActual){
    this.estado = estado;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.numPaginas = numPaginas;
    this.paginaActual = paginaActual;
  }

  public void abierto(){
    System.out.println("Libro abierto");
    this.estado = true;
  }

  public void cerrado(){
    System.out.println("Libro cerrado");
    this.estado = false;
  }

  public void mostrarLibro(){
    System.out.println("Titulo del libro: "+titulo+" ISBN: "+ISBN+" Numero de pag: "+numPaginas+" Pagina Actual: "+pagActual);
  }
}
```

Luego en LibroInfantil:

```
public class LibroInfantil extends Libro{
  private int edadRecomendada = 18;

  public class LibroInfantil(boolean estado, String titulo, String ISBN,
    int numPaginas, int pagActual, int edadRec){

    //aquí es donde la magia ocurre ya que es aquí
    //en donde llamamos al constructor de la clase
    //madre:
    super(estado,titulo,ISBN,numPaginas,pagActual);

    //inicializamos el valor que no está en la clase
    //madre:
    this.edadRecomendada = edadRec;
  }

  public boolean esRecomendable(int edadLector){
    return edadLector < this.edadRecomendada;
  }
}
```

Y eso es todo.
Otra es que puedes definir un constructor por defecto en la clase Libro, algo cómo `public Libro(){}` y sería más que suficiente.

Comment: su respuesta esta mal, es probable que sea un error de tipeo a la hora de escribir pero uste llama a super en la clase libroInfantil pero esta clase no deriva de libro en el codigo que puso.Saludos

Comment: no se si me entiende usted usa en la clase LibroInfantil -> super(estado,titulo,ISBN,numPaginas,pagActual); Cuando cuando esta no deriva de Libro en el codigo que pone Saludos

Comment: Mi clase LibroInfantil hereda de Libro

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez si la suya si estos comenterios cuando no llevan el arroba seguido de algun nombre son para el que publica la respuesta vea que esta respuesta es de otro usuario, entoces los comentarios se los dejo a el, usted los ve porque es su pregunta pero no son para usted, de serlo haci o estarian en los comentarios que tiene bajo su pregunta, o de estar en una respuesta estos llevaran arroba seguido de su nombre como este comentario, que si vera el autor de esta respuesta pero es dirijido a usted Saludos

Comment: @ Angel Angel entendido

Comment: @Omar veo que cambio su respuesta, espero cuando dije esta mal, no se lo tomara de mala manera, por eso añadie lo siguiente ->es probable que sea un error de tipeo a la hora de escribir, pero es que como estaba no le iba a funcionar Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel ningún problema, de hecho la corregí para que se ilustrara mejor lo que quería dar a entender.